# How to catch "Unable to preventDefault inside passive event listener"

Tags: javascript

Shouldn't any error in JavaScript be catchable? Why doesn't surrounding `event.preventDefault()` with a `try` `catch` block catch the error mentioned in the title?

```
document.addEventListener('click', function() {
    event.preventDefault()
    console.log('clicked!')
}, {passive: true})
```

[Here's a JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/ChefGabe/4tkL1Lhy/) for your convenience.

Comment: MDN says: *"A Boolean indicating that the listener will never call preventDefault(). If it does, the user agent should ignore it and generate a console warning."* So I guess this is not a normal error. If it was then `clicked` wouldn't be logged to the console.

Comment: @FelixKling Does that mean the Chrome user agent isn't up to spec? (it gives a big fat red error)

Comment: No, it seems to be that it does exactly what it is supposed to. It shows a warning in the console, it doesn't throw an error. Or do you mean that the warning looks more like an error?

Comment: @FelixKling yes a big annoying red error

Comment: I'm not sure there is a spec for "console warnings".

Comment: The visual appearance of the warning resembles `console.error` instead of `console.warn`, but it doesn't truly act as an error and everything runs fine after it.

Comment: You shouldn't need to catch the error anyways. You can fix this before the code even runs. If you make the event listener passive, just don't use `preventDefault()` in the listener.